# Redux-Initial Api call Not working from action creator

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have just gone through some redux tutorial and started to implement

i have one API call that has to be happen from redux as soon as page loads.. its possible with ComponentDidMount ,but i need to know how redux helps in achieving this.

For easiness i had shared the code in

- https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-sunset-s95gu?fontsize=14

My index.js look like

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import { createStore,applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import allReducer from "./reducers";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import "./styles.css";

let store = createStore(
  allReducer,
  applyMiddleware(thunk)
);

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  rootElement
);
```

My Action creater look like(action/index.js)

```
import UserApi from "../UserApi";

export function loadUserSuccess(user) {
  return { type: "LOAD_USER_SUCCESS", user };
}
export function loadUsers() {
  return function(dispatch) {
    return UserApi.getAllUsers()
      .then(user => {
        console.log("midhun");
        dispatch(loadUserSuccess(user));
      })
      .catch(error => {
        throw error;
      });
  };
}
```

and its subsequent api caliing function look like

```
class UserApi {
  static getAllUsers() {
    return fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then(response => {
        console.log("response", response);
        return response.json();
      })
      .catch(error => {
        return error;
      });
  }
}

export default UserApi;
```

My Reducer look like

```
import initialState from "./InitialState";

export default function IsLoggedReducer(state = initialState.user, action) {
  console.log(state, action);
  switch (action.type) {
    case "LOAD_USER_SUCCESS":
      return state;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

and my App.js look like

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import * as userActions from "./action/index";
import UserList from "./UserList";

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>MYpage</h1>
        <UserList user={this.props.user} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  return {
    user: state.user
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

I had put couple of console in action creator and its subsequent function,but its not triggering.

Any help will be much much apreciated and will be highly help for beginners

You guys can check the complete set of code

**https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-sunset-s95gu?fontsize=14**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the info lavor gaved, since you use combineReducers, you need to access to state by using your reducer key.

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import {loadUsers} from "./action/index";
import UserList from "./UserList";

class App extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.loadUsers();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>MYpage</h1>
        <UserList users={this.props.users} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  return {
    users: state.IsLoggedReducer
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {loadUsers})(App);
```

I also made some corrections in the reducer file, we need to return the new state with the given payload.

```
import initialState from "./InitialState";

export default function IsLoggedReducer(state = initialState.user, action) {
  console.log("ap", action.payload);
  switch (action.type) {
    case "LOAD_USER_SUCCESS":
      return [...action.payload]
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

And action file:

```
import UserApi from "../UserApi";

export function loadUserSuccess(users) {
  return { type: "LOAD_USER_SUCCESS", payload: users };
}
export function loadUsers() {
  return function(dispatch) {
    return UserApi.getAllUsers()
      .then(users => {
        dispatch(loadUserSuccess(users));
      })
      .catch(error => {
        throw error;
      });
  };
}
```

You can check this codesandbox for the working app.

https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-colden-v6r6w

Comment: Also can you tell me whats the significance of switch case.. since its been cald just reducer name -IsLoggedReducer
 return {
    users: state.IsLoggedReducer
  };
whats significance of different types ?

Comment: I didn't understand what you meant.

Comment: state.IsLoggedReducer  here IsLoggedReducer comes from here: const allReducer = combineReducers({ IsLoggedReducer: IsLoggedReducer});

Comment: What if i have different cases,means if IsLoggedReducer have many cases,how it will understand its calling LOAD_USER_SUCCESS. Am sorry am new top redux

Comment: please have a look at this example in the official docs: https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/basic-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

You are not dispatching your action, try to do it in componentDidMount (you need to map dispatch to props first):

App.js

```js
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.loadUsers();
}

// ...

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  return {
    user: state.user
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    loadUsers: () => dispatch(userActions.loadUsers())
  };
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```